# Dijkstra's Bankers Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, bankers-algorithm

Could somebody please provide a step-through approach to solving the following problem using the Banker's Algorithm? How do I determine whether a "safe-state" exists? What is meant when a process can "run to completion"?

In this example, I have four processes and 10 instances of the same resource.

```
          Resources Allocated | Resources Needed
Process A                   1                  6
Process B                   1                  5
Process C                   2                  4
Process D                   4                  7
```

Comment: is this homework? if so, please add the homework tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banker%27s_algorithm),

> A state (as in the above example) is considered safe if it is possible for all processes to finish executing (terminate). Since the system cannot know when a process will terminate, or how many resources it will have requested by then, the system assumes that all processes will eventually attempt to acquire their stated maximum resources and terminate soon afterward. This is a reasonable assumption in most cases since the system is not particularly concerned with how long each process runs (at least not from a deadlock avoidance perspective). Also, if a process terminates without acquiring its maximum resources, it only makes it easier on the system.

A process can run to completion when the number of each type of resource that it needs is available, between itself and the system.  If a process needs 8 units of a given resource, and has allocated 5 units, then it can run to completion if there are at least 3 more units available that it can allocate.

Given your example, the system is managing a single resource, with 10 units available.  The running processes have already allocated 8 (1+1+2+4) units, so there are 2 units left.  The amount that any process needs to complete is its maximum less whatever it has already allocated, so at the start, A needs 5 more (6-1), B needs 4 more (5-1), C needs 2 more (4-2), and D needs 3 more (7-4).  There are 2 available, so Process C is allowed to run to completion, thus freeing up 2 units (leaving 4 available).  At this point, either B or D can be run (we'll assume D).  Once D has completed, there will be 8 units available, after which either A or B can be run (we'll assume A).  Once A has completed, there will be 9 units available, and then B can be run, which will leave all 10 units left for further work.  Since we can select an ordering of processes that will allow all processes to be run, the state is considered 'safe'.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Resources Allocated | Resources Needed    claim
  Process A      1                  6            5
  Process B      1                  5            4
  Process C      2                  4            2
  Process D      4                  7            3
```

Total resources allocated is 8
Hence 2 resources are yet to be allocated hence that is allocated to process C. and process c after finishing relieves 4 resources that can be given to process B ,Process B after finishing relives 5 resources which is allocated to PROCESS A the n process A after finishing allocates 2 resources to process D